# The type <type> exists in both 'A' and 'B'

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Now I know there are a number of these questions already up here, but after flipping through them, I haven't found one that solves my specific problem.

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4.5 project. I used NuGet and added Newtonsoft.Json to the project. As soon as I used it in my code (to do some serialization in camel-case), my project no longer builds correctly with the following error:

> The type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver' exists in both 'C:..\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Blend\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" and 'C:..\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\myProject\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'

Unfortunately, it's the same file down to the public key on each so I can't use the dependency assembly reference in Web.config (as suggested elsewhere). I would prefer to use the dll retrieved via NuGet so upgrades to new versions are easier.

Additionally, neither one is in the Temporary Internet folder, so I can't simply delete that and have it work either.

How can I go about specifying the specific assembly file I want to use so I can build the project correctly? Thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Xaniff, open your project file manually and look for Newtonsoft. You will more than likely find an item group with a reference to a version that is not matching your nuget package.. In my case I found this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
        <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.5.0.6\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

I deleted this item group, closed the project file, reloaded, and all was well.

Comment: This did the trick. For anyone that encounters this same problem, note that you shouldn't delete the reference in the item group to the higher version number, but rather just the lower one.

Comment: Woked for me as well. The problem started after having updated my Newtonsoft library through the Packet Manager Console.

Comment: in that file you should merge the item groups to one item group and delete lower versions of the refrence

Comment: I had the problem building the app in Azure devops pipelines, your answer has fixed the issue. Thank you.